# "I wrote the article with simple words for my students to read it faster." - correct?

Tags: structure

**Example 1**

> "They gave their bodies a few days for **them** to recover."

"Them" refers to "their bodies."

**Example 2**

> "The coach gave my body a few days for **it** to get enough rest."

"It" refers to "my body."

**Example 3**

> "I wrote the article with simple words for my students to read it faster."

Are the examples correct? Can I use to-infinitive like this?

Comment: Asking for something to be proofread is off-topic here.

Comment: The mention of bodies seems unnecessary in the first two. You give a _person_ time to rest; it should be understood that that means resting their body.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly acceptable.  The object of the preposition implies the subject of the infinitive complement.  You can get plenty of simple examples:

> I am hoping for Joe to meet him.